# How to restore GBWA backup on new phone to GBWA app

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm simultaneously running Whatsapp & GBwhatsapp on my phone for both of my numbers.

For me it's easy to just transfer Whatsapp data to new phone. However, when its come to GBWhatsapp i feel like there is no one how can actually help to transfer GBWhatsapp data to new phone on GBWhatsapp application.

I have purchased a new phone, now trying all effort to get the GBWhatsapp data to be restore on new phone on GBWA app.

I tried compressing GBWA data using ES file explorer and moved to new phone and verified my number with GBWA. However, after verifying the account i do not get any option to restore even-though backup folder already exist on new phone.

As I don't wanted to loose my data, i again verified my account on old phone and removed GBWA from new phone. I have read multiple articles and checked many videos but didn't find them useful in my case.

Could you please help me to get my issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

if you do the following it must work:

go to gbwhatsapp on your old phone choose GB Settings 
--> other MODS
-->6.7 Backup data (i do for secority reasons also the following, go to gbwhatsapp--> settings--> chats-- make backup) 
then transfer the    whole GBWHatsapp map to sdcard, and take it out of your old phone.
install GBWhatsapp on your new phone and DONT OPEN IT YET
now put in your sdcard with the backup of GBWHatsapp in your new phone
--> copy GBWhatsapp map to internal memory
--> then open GBwhastapp and choose for restore